# MAMP Pro + Espionage folder encryption = 403 error?

Tags: apache, encryption, mamp, httpd.conf

I'm using MAMP PRO on my OS X 10.6 with Espionage to encrypt my ~/Sites folder (where MAMP is pulling my virtual hosts from).

I'm having trouble having MAMP's Apache follow the symlink that Espionage automatically creates to /Volumes/EspionageMounts/lee/3042560432 (I believe this changes all the time, so cannot be static).

My 'Sites' folder is owned by lee/staff.

The volume Espionage mounts seems to be owned by the same.

I have set MAMP Pro to use user 'lee' for Apache.

FollwSymLinks is set in my test.dev virtual host.

And yet, any Apache request to test.dev/whatever.html yields a 403 Forbidden.

The Apache error logs shows:

> [Sun Jul 18 08:39:14 2010] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not
>   allowed: /Users/lee/Sites

What am I missing?

Comment: It's probably a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the target folder of the symlink has sufficient permissions for "others."

Try checking the option "Public mountpoint" on Espionage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You must select "Public mountpoint" under Espionage settings for your ~Sites folder. Click "Save Changes" and you should see your local sites properly when your folder isn't locked.